Why are the results always different from my tests?
I am currently developing a Plinko game using Matter.js. I’ve written code to ensure that the result is always determined by the ball’s initial position, without any external influence.
For example, in the test environment, when I drop the ball from x: 100, y: 0, it always lands in the same spot. However, during actual gameplay, the results are inconsistent and differ from the test results.
dropBall(path: number[] = [], start: number, test: boolean = false) {
        const { friction, frictionAirByRowCount } = PlinkoEngine.ballFrictions;

        // const startX = this.canvas.width / 2;
        const startX = start
        const startY = 0;
        const ballRadius = this.pinRadius * 2;

        const ball = Bodies.circle(startX, startY, ballRadius, {
            label: 'ball',
            restitution: 0.9,
            friction,
            frictionAir: frictionAirByRowCount[this.rowCount],
            collisionFilter: {
                category: PlinkoEngine.BALL_CATEGORY,
                mask: PlinkoEngine.PIN_CATEGORY,
            },
            render: { fillStyle: '#ff0000' },
            path: path,
            start: start,
            test: test
        });
        Composite.add(this.engine.world, ball);

        this.gameStore.updateBetAmountOfExistingBalls(ball.id, this.betAmount);
        this.gameStore.updateBalance(-this.betAmount);
    }


There's not enough information to help here. Please share a [mcve]. What strategy are you using to make it deterministic? In the meantime, In the plinko game written with the matter.js engine library, how to make the ball always fall into the pre-planned position may be relevant (there are many existing threads on deterministic Plinko in MJS, somehow it's a common use case I guess).
